# Google Cloud Endpoints JS Client will not Load - Getting 404 with broken URL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

This is probably going to need more information than I provide, but since I have no idea what is going on, I'll start with what I know.

I am using GAE with Google Cloud Endpoints.

My API loads and works great when accessing it from the API explorer, but it will NOT work when I load it in the web app.

```
function startApp(user) {

    var appName = 'pwLandlordApp',
        app = packageApp(appName);

    configureApp(app, user);
    angular.bootstrap(document, [appName]);

}

function verifyAuthenticated() {
    gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function (resp) {

        var authenticated = !resp.code,
            user;

        if (authenticated) {
            user = resp;
            startApp(user);

        } else {
            $('#manualAuthenticationLink').show();
        }

    });
}

function authenticate(immediateMode) {

    var callback = verifyAuthenticated,
        clientId = {
            development: '227265048827-17u88it981ie38hopqr8nl7tnep0d8l2.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            production: '227265048827-5f98s99qoigh8f0tmp106uplek8g7mq5.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        };

    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: clientId.development,
        scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'],
        immediate: immediateMode
    }, callback);

}

function authenticateAutomatically() {
    var immediateMode = true;
    authenticate(immediateMode);
}

function authenticateManually() {
    var immediateMode = false;
    authenticate(immediateMode);
}

function loadResources() {

    var appRootUrl = {
            development: 'http://localhost:8080/_ah/api',
            production: 'https://property-management-suite.appspot.com/_ah/api'
        },
        numberOfResourcesToLoad = 2,
        verifyAllResourcesLoaded;

    verifyAllResourcesLoaded = function () {
        numberOfResourcesToLoad -= 1;
        if (numberOfResourcesToLoad === 0) {
            authenticateAutomatically();
        }
    };

    // If loading additional resources change numberOfResourcesToLoad appropriately.
    gapi.client.load('propertyWrasslerApi', 'v1', verifyAllResourcesLoaded, appRootUrl.development);
    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', verifyAllResourcesLoaded);

}

function init() {
    loadResources();
}
```

Keep getting the following error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/propertyWrasslerApi/v1/rpc?fields=methods%2F*%2Fid&pp=0
```

**Tried checking out an earlier commit that I know worked and the problem persisted, WTF!** So not sure what is going on.

Help, please! Been at this for hours.

**UPDATE:**

My web.xml file. I know It's empty but that has always worked for me as I only have an API.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         version="2.5" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

</web-app>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

appengine-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>property-management-suite</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Can you please re-title?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure what to name it.

Comment: My bet is that it is in the repeated `_ah/api/_ah/api`.  Your Root url is being appended with another `_ah/api`.  Also, do you have `_ah/api` handler in your app.yaml?  `https://property-management-suite.appspot.com/_ah/api` is not found, so my bet is that you don't have its handler in app.yaml.

Comment: @GAEfan Yea, there is something there. Also using Java. What's the equivalent?

Comment: DO you have an appengine-web.xml:   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig

Comment: @GAEfan Added up top.

Comment: Yeah, a Google bug.  It is adding the discovery path to your url.  Argh.  You'll have to wait for a conclusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the javascript client library. Are you loading it directly from https://apis.google.com?

Update: This is a bug. Google is looking into it:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=147

Comment: Is this bug breaking every webapp in the world using Endpoints?

Comment: Is it me or is this issue still not resolved yet? @MarcM.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem with an app in python. It looks like a problem in the Google Javascript Library (apis.google.com/js/client.js). I'm currently looking for an older version of the client.